# Hey python to resolve tcl variable? Nuke

Tags: python, tcl, nuke

So, I'm trying to get python  to print a string that had a tcl variable in it, with the result of that variable. I'm using nuke, in case that matters for my code.

```
[set THIS image] 
Ln = "/Test/still/testing/$THIS\_clean_v001"
print(Ln) # this prints exactly the above

G = nuke.tcl('[puts "$THIS"] ')
```

Would `print(G)` return the word image or no?

I could then sub it in. The problem is the text field I'm entering that tcl in to solves it inside the program fine, but then as soon as I send it to process it takes the `$THIS` literally.

Comment: Can you link us to the docs for `nuke.tcl`?

Comment: not in nuke at the moment but it's basically: nuke.tcl(script, *args) if that helps. I'll look online in the mean time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things to note:

1. Tcl `puts` does not return a value. It sounds like you want [Tcl `set`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/set.htm), which does.
2. The docs for `nuke.tcl` at http://www.nukepedia.com/reference/Python indicate:

   > `tcl(command, arg, arg, ...)`
   >
   > Run a tcl command. The arguments must be strings and passed to the command. If no arguments are given and the command has whitespace in it then it is instead interpreted as a tcl program (this is depreciated)

Rather than invoking it as a full script, it seems you could both use the non-deprecated version and get the behavior you want by using:

```
G = nuke.tcl("set", "THIS")
```

Whic should reutrn the value of the `THIS` variable.

Comment: I though set, well, at the variable, not returned it. I've already set the variable elsewhere. An I wrong?

Comment: With one argument, set returns the current value of the variable. With two, it sets the new value then returns that.

Comment: Aghhh okay thanks. Slightly new to tcl and must have missed that in the docs

Comment: Tcl's manual pages are occasionally slightly gnostic, and often pay dividends when read very carefully. If you think that a specific bit of documentation is too obscure, file a bug report against Tcl so that we know to improve it. (When filing, mention the specific page under http://www.tcl.tk/man so we know what you're talking about; those are all official HTML builds from the source tree.) They are, however, fundamentally a reference and not a tutorial. We have those as well, but separate…

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a one-shot expansion of all TCL variables in a string using the TCL `subst` command.

```python
nuke.tcl('set', 'THIS', 'image')
p = '/Test/still/testing/$THIS\_clean_v001'
print nuke.tcl('subst', p)
```

The result of this will be the properly-expanded string: `'/Test/still/testing/image_clean_v001'`

Documentation for subst can be found here: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/subst.htm